# responsive logo centered in navigation

Tags: css, html

Hi there I have a horizontal menu with the logo in the center, can't seem to get it inline but still looks good in all browsers so far.

Now when in responsive mode I would like it to show the logo all the time at the top and the button to go underneath to show/hide the menu.
At the moment in responsive it hides the logo then when the Show Menu is clicked it shows the menu with the logo in the middle of the ul.

Here is the code so far a bit messy at the moment.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {

    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #F1F6F8;
}

a {

    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3F5767;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #524C56;
}

#wrapper {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* Logo code can go here */
ul li a.logo {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcqW.png) no-repeat center;
    height:76px;
    width:175px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


nav {
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0  10px 0 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #3F5767;
}

/* Start controls checkbox change button */
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover{  /* Maybe remove this */
        display: block;
        width: auto;
}       

input[type=checkbox] {
        display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
        display: block;
}

.show-menu{
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3F5767;
        background: #424242;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3px o;
        display: none;
}


.thing:before {
        content: "Show Menu";
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .thing:before {
        content: "Close Menu";
}


@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
        ul{position: static;
        display: none;
}

li{
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        /*border-bottom: 2px solid #676767;*/
}


ul li, li a{
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 15px;
}
.show-menu{
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 3px 0 0 0;
}
}
/* End controls checkbox change button */

@media print {#ghostery-purple-box {display:none !important}}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Coast Fm Tasmania</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <nav>

        <input id="show-menu" role="button" type="checkbox">
        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu thing"> &nbsp </label>

        <ul id="menu">
            <li> 
            <a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">On-Air</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a class="logo" href="index.html"></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also here is the Logo
[Coast FM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcqW.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another logo in a `div` that will be your "hidden logo".

```
<input id="show-menu" role="button" type="checkbox">
<div class="hidden">
 <a class="hidden-logo" href="index.html"></a>
 <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu thing"> &nbsp </label>
</div>
```

Then you can display it and hide it whenever you wish.

```
.hidden {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #424242;
    display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
    .hidden {
        display:flex;
    }
}
.hidden-logo {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcqW.png) no-repeat center;
    height:23px;
    background-size:50%;
    width:175px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
}
```

Here is an example

https://jsfiddle.net/jrdkp7ph/2/

Comment: Hi I like it a lot how you did this.  ? it does not show any responsive in Safari

Comment: Hey, I just tested on Safari 10.1 and it works fine for me. Can you show me a pic of your issue?

Comment: HI thanks I like it didn't think to hide I changed the flexbox code a little so it works in Safari.  Is there a way to get rid of the white space where the logo is hidden in the responsive menu?

Comment: You can use `display:none;` to hide that `li` that contains the image

Comment: Safari on my windows system is only 5.1.7 it works great thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks I fixed it thank you for your help. 12:30 am here so later today I will start to do  the rest of the site now that is out of the way.  Thanks again

Comment: Just noticed the text does not change to Close Menu now so I will try to work that out again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery and add desired list dynamically

Do check code here for example: https://jsbin.com/zusunidupo/1/edit?css,js,output
Need to execute below code block every time when window resizes(in link provided executes on first load only)

```
if ($(window).width() < 760) {
$('<li><a class="logo" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcqW.png"><img border="0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcqW.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>').insertAfter($('li:eq(4)'))
}
else {
$("#menu").prepend('<li><a class="logo" href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcqW.png"><img border="0" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcqW.png" width="50" height="50"></a></li>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i think your html code many change just  suggest improve

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {

    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: 5px;
    background: #F1F6F8;
}

a {

    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3F5767;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #524C56;
}

#wrapper {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* Logo code can go here */
ul li a.logo {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcqW.png) no-repeat center;
    height:76px;
    width:175px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dcqW.png) no-repeat center;
    height:76px;
    width:175px;
    display:block;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0  10px 0 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #3F5767;
}

/* Start controls checkbox change button */
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover{  /* Maybe remove this */
        display: block;
        width: auto;
}       

input[type=checkbox] {
        display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
        display: block;
}

.show-menu{
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3F5767;
        background: #424242;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 3px o;
        display: none;
}


.thing:before {
        content: "Show Menu";
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .thing:before {
        content: "Close Menu";
}


@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
ul{position: static;
        display: none;
}
ul li a.logo { display: none; } 

li{
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-size: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        /*border-bottom: 2px solid #676767;*/
}


ul li, li a{
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 15px;
}
.show-menu{
        display: block;
        width: auto;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 3px 0 0 0;
}
}
/* End controls checkbox change button */

@media print {#ghostery-purple-box {display:none !important}}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Coast Fm Tasmania</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <nav>

        <input id="show-menu" role="button" type="checkbox">
        <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu thing">  <a class="logo" href="index.html"></a>  &nbsp </label>
       

        <ul id="menu">
            <li> 
            <a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">On-Air</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a class="logo" href="index.html"></a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Sport</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you it was a mess as I took it from another site I was working on but decided to put the logo in this one.